# Can any body help me in drawing the graph of |x|+3|y|=3 (to be used for finding area under it)

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I am able to draw graph for y=|x+2|,but i can not make |x|+3|y|=3 graph

Comment: The straight-forward (but _slightly_ long-and-boring) way is to split into four cases depending on whether $x\geq0$ and whether $y\geq0$. I suggest you do that if you can't see the solution intuitively.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Case 1) $x>0, y>0: x+3y=3$

Case 2) $x>0, y<0: x-3y=3$

Case 3) $x<0, y>0: -x+3y=3$

Case 4) $x<0, y<0: x+3y=-3$

[image]